# WatiN: Unable to click an Element twice - "Could not find element" error

Tags: c#, watin

I am running into an issue where I need to click on an element twice. The first time the element is clicked it expands a tree on the page, the second time closes the tree. There is no issue when clicking the element the first time.

Here is the part of the HTML code I am working with: (The element I am clicking is the 'a' tag.)

```
<div id="uasMainForm:uasTabs:0:agencyTree-d-rt-c" name="c">
    <div title="" class="iceTreeRow" id="uasMainForm:uasTabs:0:agencyTree-d-4" name="nd">
        <a id="uasMainForm:uasTabs:0:agencyTree:4" onclick="document.forms['uasMainForm']['uasMainForm:uasMainForm:uasTabs:0:agencyTree_idtn'].value='4';iceSubmitPartial( document.forms['uasMainForm'], this,event); return false;" onblur="setFocus('');" href="javascript:;">
```

The weird thing is, if I run the second click immediately after running the first it closes the tree perfectly, but if I break it up with a MessageBox or some other code it throws an error when trying to perform the second click.

Here is code that works:

```
agency = ie.ElementOfType<Div>(Find.ByText(agencyName));
agencyTab = agency.ElementWithTag("a", Find.ByIndex(0));
agencyTab.Click();

//MessageBox.Show("Hey!");
agencyTab.Click();
```

Here is the code that does not work:

```
agency = ie.ElementOfType<Div>(Find.ByText(agencyName));
agencyTab = agency.ElementWithTag("a", Find.ByIndex(0));
agencyTab.Click();

MessageBox.Show("Hey!");
agencyTab.Click();
```

The above code throws the error: Could not find A element tag matching criteria: Index = 0

I have also tried Find.ById instead of ByIndex with the same result. Can anyone shed some light on what could be causing this error when breaking up the two click events, but not when the click events happen back to back?

Comment: What kind of class is `MessageBox`? I can't see that is a part of the WatiN framework...

Comment: And also: if you step through that code in the debugger, what happens? Does the code step to the next statement immediately after `MessageBox.Show("Hey!")`, or does it wait till you for instance close/click on the message box?

Comment: MessageBox is from class System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox. The code waits for you to click ok in the message box. I just noticed, in the code with MessageBox commented out, I get the error if I step through the code slowly. It seems that seconds after the first .Click(), agency.Exists becomes 'False'. I'm not sure why this would happen, because that Div is obviously still in the html code.

Comment: Does it make any difference if you call `agencyTab.Refresh()` after showing the message box?

Comment: I tried that also, but with no success. I guess it's possible that it is having trouble finding the text at `agency = ie.ElementOfType<Div>(Find.ByText(agencyName));` after the first .Click takes place. I know that the click event for the <a> tag adds additional divs, but it doesn't get rid of the text I am searching on.

Comment: Is the dialog closing? The dialog could be taking focus from your page and then WatiN is looking in the dialog for your tree. Make sure you are closing the dialog box.

Comment: After the first click what is the value of agencyTab.Exists ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure why this issue was occuring but I found a way around it. First I save the Id of the containing Div right before I do the first click:

```
var agency = ie.ElementOfType<Div>(Find.ByText(agencyName));

//Set current agency Id
currentAgency = agency.Id;

var agencyTab = agency.ElementWithTag("a", Find.ByIndex(0));
agencyTab.Click();
```

Then, when I want to perform the second click, I use the Id I saved earlier to find the containing Div again:

```
//Close old agency's tree
var agency2 = ie.ElementOfType<Div>(Find.ById(currentAgency));
var agencyTab2 = agency2.ElementWithTag("a", Find.ByIndex(0));
agencyTab2.Click();
```